# My windows phone application runs when ran though visual studio (onclick of device button) but when I disconnect and run it doesn't?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, filepicker

I have written file picker code in my project. When i run the project in my windows phone by clicking on device button in visual studio, the app runs fine(I mean it opens pictures library and i can select a photo and preview it).

But when I disconnect my usb and then open the app in the phone and when i open pictures library on click of a button , the pictures library opens briefly and then the app crashes immediately(My app closes).
Can anyone please help me with this??

Comment: So, at what exact time is your app crashing? Does the file picker open briefly then crash immediately, or does your app crash once you've chosen a file in the picker?

Comment: File picker opens briefly then crash immediately!!!

Comment: @Decade Moon Do u know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the blog post , the AndContinue method run in a different process and to do so, the current running app goes into the background or even gets closed sometimes, that is what you are experiencing in your app as far i can tell but not sure why different things happening during debug & deploy.
There must be a callback inside app.xaml.cs specifically to handle the condition when calling application(which was sent into background) comes in foreground, read this blog post carefully & you'll understand as what you need to change in your code : 
using-the-andcontinue-methods-in-windows-phone
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/05/08/using-the-andcontinue-methods-in-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1-apps.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with this issue and one of the reasons why there are differences between debug and deploy is because of the suspending event.
During debug, the application does not actually get suspended until you manually do it through Lifecycle Events. This means that when you pick a file on debug and the app is put to the background to load the file picker, it is not actually suspended, while when the app is deployed, it actually gets suspended.

Look into your app_resuming method and OnSuspending methods in your app.xaml that may be causing errors not occurring during debug.